# Php trim get value characters that are not in array

Tags: php, string, codeigniter

I'm using the codeigniter framework and utilizing the    uri->segment(); function

I have an array:

```
$brand_array = array("Alpine" => "Alpine", "Atrend" => "Atrend");

if ($this->uri->segment(3) && array_key_exists($this->uri->segment(3),
                                                         $brand_array)) {
$mm = $brand_array[$this->uri->segment(3)];


    echo $mm;

    }
```

I want to use PHP to trim any characters that do not equal an array value

so if the user types this into the url example.com/brands/DDDAlpine

I would want to trim all of those characters before Alpine

is this going to be a fairly complex function?

Will I need to use preg_replace and write my own string pattern?

Comment: Complex? No. Expensive and unrealistic? Yes.

Comment: How do you suggest I tackle this problem?

Comment: Actually I take back the unrealistic part. Where I work we acquire sites all the time that have thousands of indexed pages on Google and we have to write the most gnarly hacks when we migrate the sites to CodeIgniter to account for all the legacy URL's and whatnot. I stand by the expensive comment though. We have to rely on extensive caching to make up for all the excess logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that will accommodate an exact match, a single possibility, multiple possible matches, and will acknowledge no matches:

```
$brand_array = array("Alpine" => "Alpine", "Atrend" => "Atrend");

if($this->uri->segment(3))
{
    // Check for exact match
    if(array_key_exists($this->uri->segment(3),$brand_array))
    {
        $brand = $this->uri->segment(3);
    }

    // If no exact match, lets look for the brand somewhere in the uri segment
    else
    {
        $uris = array_keys($brand_array);
        $potential_matches = array();
        foreach($uris as $uri)
        {
            if(stristr($uri,$this->uri->segment(3)))
            {
                $potential_matches[] = $uri;
            }
        }

        // Check length of potential matches. If only 1, lets use it
        if(count($potential_matches) < 1)
        {
            // No match, fail or redirect
            echo 'No match';
        }
        else if(count($potential_matches) == 1)
        {
            $brand = $potential_matches[0];
        }
        else
        {
            // Show all possible matches...
            print_r($potential_matches);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just tried this out and it works fine but when I type /DDDalpine it stil gives me 'No matches'

Comment: In the no matches condition, do another iteration of the uri's and swap the `stristr()` arguments. For example, `Alp` is in `Alpine`, but `DDDalpine` is not - however, `Alpine` is in `DDDalpine` if that makes sense. You can't assume how the user will mistype your urls so accommodating both makes sense in this case.

Comment: Thank you for this BTW. Can you give me a quick overview of swaping the stristr() argument?

Comment: Simplest is just `if(stristr($uri,$this->uri->segment(3)) || stristr($this->uri->segment(3),$uri))`

Answer (score 0):

I could imagine only looping through array and doing a regular expression match for every brand

```
<?php
$mm = '';
if ($this->uri->segment(3)) {
  foreach ($brand_array as $brand) {
    if (preg_match('/^.*' . $brand . '.*$/i', $this->uri->segment(3)) {
      $mm = $brand;
      break;
    }
  }
}
echo $mm;
```

Comment: What if the array was `array("Alpine"=>"Alpine","Alpinestars"=>"Alpinestars",.....)`? Your solution would never acknowledge the Alpine brand.

Comment: You mean, it never would acknowledge `Alpinestars`. He never said, that he wants to see _all_ matching values of array. The user typing in `DDDAlpine` really means `Alpine`, but who said, that `Alpinestars` couldn't be a failure by user, too (and he also means `Alpine`)

Comment: Ah yep I missed the `break;` in there. Thought it was reassigning itself to all proceeding matches, but you're right it wouldn't get past the first match.